# Server side software to auto-delete MySQL database records

Tags: windows, linux, database, mysql

I have a **MySQL** database that has a table with records which are valid for a day.
Is there a server side software that can easily delete records in respect to a field in the table.I know one you can use cron jobs for this, but is there an *all in one* software that actively deletes records in MySQL database>table.

I am open to suggestions on both *Linux* and *Windows*.

Comment: What do you mean by maintains records? Could you give an example of what the database structure would look like for custom solutions?

Comment: @Tom let say resetting values in table of "game high scores".The high scores would be reset evey week..etc

Comment: I have edited the question, my main concern is that creating crons sometimes is too hard as it is a new area of study/exploration for me.